Are MPI messages of different tags matched sequentially?
I'm trying to build an MPI program that sends two types of messages from an undermined number of processors to process A using nonblocking send (the program is randomized, and I am using tags to demarcate which message is of which type. The first type of message is used to send a vector of data, and the second type is used to tell the process no more messages are going to be sent. The code looks like this:
void send_data() {
   /*... initialization of variables ...*/
   MPI_Isend( loc_buffer1.data(),        //Address of the message we are sending.
           bufferlen,                  //Number of elements handled by that address.
           MPI_INT,            //MPI_TYPE of the message we are sending.
           new_proc,           //Rank of receiving process
           1,                  //Message Tag
           MPI_COMM_WORLD,      //MPI Communicator
           &request1 ); }

}


void check_for_criteria() {
   if (criteria_met) { send_data(); }

   // Telling the target process there is no more data to be sent 

   MPI_Isend( NULL,        //Address of the message we are sending.
           0,                  //Number of elements handled by that address.
           MPI_CHAR,            //MPI_TYPE of the message we are sending.
           new_proc,           //Rank of receiving process
           2,                  //Message Tag
           MPI_COMM_WORLD,      //MPI Communicator
           &request1 ); }
}


void receive_parallel_comm_helper(...) {

            int test_flag1 = 0;
            int test_flag2 = 0;
            MPI_Status status1;
            MPI_Status status2;
            std::vector<int> new_loc_buffer1(9);
            
            std::vector<bool> stop_par_Array(num_procs, 0);
            stop_par_Array[rank] = 1;
            bool stop_par = 0;
            
            while ((!stop_par)) {
                for (int i=0; i<num_procs; i++) {
                    if (i != rank) {
                        stop_par = 1;

                        status1.MPI_TAG = 0;
                        status2.MPI_TAG = 0;

                        test_flag1 = 0;
                        test_flag2 = 0;
                        MPI_Iprobe(i, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &test_flag1, &status1);

                        if ((status1.MPI_TAG == 1) (test_flag1)) {
                            MPI_Recv(new_loc_buffer1.data(), 9, MPI_INT, i, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status1);
                        }

                        test_flag2 = 0;

                        MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &test_flag2, &status2);
                        if ((status2.MPI_TAG == 2) && (test_flag2)) {
                           MPI_Recv(NULL, 0, MPI_CHAR, status2.MPI_SOURCE, par_done_tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
                            stop_par_Array[status2.MPI_SOURCE] = 1;
                        }
                        for (int j = 0; j < num_procs; j++) {
                            stop_par &= stop_par_Array[j];
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
                
            MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        }

 


void main_function() {
    while (some_criteria) {
       ...
       check_for_criteria();
       MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
       receive_parallel_comm_helper();
       ...
    }

}


Essentially, when main_function() is called, each process checks some criteria to see if it should send data to another process. Whether data is sent or not, a null message is then sent to indicate that the sending process is complete. Then, each process enters the receive_parallel_comm_helper() function, and a while loop spins while waiting to receive: 1. data and 2. a null message indicating the data sending from that processor is complete. However, I am currently not getting the desired behavior - data is often sent but received in a later iteration of the main_function() while loop, as the null message is for some reason received first. I know that message sequentiality is guaranteed by MPI, but this code relies on the assumption that message sending is sequential for messages with different tags - is this not the case? If not, how could this code be corrected?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Even if MPI does maintain sequential queuing of different tags, you have a race condition because you do separate Iprobe calls for tags 1 and 2:



time
sender
receiver




1

Loop 0: Iprobe tag 1 - no


2
send tag 1



3
send tag 2



4

Loop 0: Iprobe tag 2 - yes


5

Loop 0: recv tag 2


6

Loop 1: Iprobe tag 1 - yes


7

Loop 1: recv tag 1




One possible fix is to use MPI_ANY_TAG in a single Iprobe call instead of (multiple) Iprobe with 1 followed by Iprobe with 2.
This would fix the issue if MPI does maintain sequential queuing of different tags.
But, I don't know MPI well enough to know if it does sequential queuing. You could test this by modifying your code to do only one Iprobe with the MPI_ANY_TAG as mentioned.

Another way is to have create a common message header struct:
#define MAX_SIZE        2048

struct mymsg {
    int msg_type;                           // message type
    unsigned int msg_seqno;                 // sequence number
    unsigned int msg_count;                 // number of elements
    union {
        unsigned int msg_1[MAX_SIZE];       // type 1 data
        unsigned float msg_2[MAX_SIZE];     // type 2 data
    };
};

Then, always send using a single tag value (e.g. 1) and decode your data according to the msg_type field in your struct.

With such a message struct, you could also use different MPI tags but hold the message in a local queue if you get a sequence number that isn't sequential.
That is, if you get a sequence such as: 1, 4, 2, 5, 3:

Receive 1 -- process 1
Receive 4 -- hold 4
Receive 2 -- process 2
Receive 5 -- hold 5
Receive 3 -- process 3, 4, 5

Loosely, this is how networking software reassembles TCP messages that are split and the segments arrive out of order.

When using a single probe to check for a message as suggested, the iprobe can also replaced by a blocking probe, assuming that eventually a message will arrive.

An other option is to use MPI_Improbe() and then MPI_Mrecv() in order to receive the message you just probed.

@GillesGouaillardet mprobe doesn't help for the race condition in this case. The messages with different tags are simply not ordered according to MPI. Therefore anytag would also not help in this situation

Order messages are non overtaking in MPI https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-1.1/mpi-11-html/node41.html so MPI_ANY_TAG can be used if (I believe this is the case here) data is sent before the termination message.

Using a single blocking probe call with the MPI_ANY_TAG and MPI_ANY_SOURCE
tags, then separating messages based on the MPI_TAG field worked (the solution above by @Craig-Estey)! As
@GillesGouaillardet suggested (and after doing some more reading), the MPI messages are sequentially received (irrespective of tag) given that they all match the same probe call.
